# Node permissions - administer content

Tags: 8, users

Can someone explain to me how node permissions are structured (or point me in the direction of a detailed list) - I'm trying to setup an editor role and want this to have full access to every content types.

It appears the only way is to tick 'Bypass content access control'?

Yet 'Administer Content' ("Promote, change ownership, edit revisions, and perform other tasks across all content types.") doesn't seem to do very much?

For example, I tick 'Administer Content' and untick 'Bypass Content Access Control', I don't seem to be able to "Promote" anything using the Actions dropdown, nor do I have an edit button next to anything on /admin/content, or any other way of accessing revisions or the ownership settings.

If I tick all the options for one content type, e.g. Basic Page, I get full access to those nodes, as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I now understand how this works:

If you want a user to be able to edit all content types, regardless, you **are** supposed to use "Bypass Content Access Types".

"Administer Content" allows people without "Bypass Content Access Types" access to the Author and Promotion panels on the rhside of the node edit screen. i.e. they can change the Author (UID) and the creation date/time, and can either promote the content to the homepage or make it sticky.

"Administer Content" also gives access to the Revisions tab for all content types - but those permissions are duplicated - a user may already have them if type-specific revision permissions have been set, e.g:

- Basic page: Delete revisions
- Basic page: Revert revisions

(Note: Administer Content used to be called Administer Nodes and the latter name is still used internally.)

Comment: In addition to allowing access to the right-hand side panels you mentioned, the "Administer Content" permission also seems to give users access to the "Published" checkbox (assuming you're not using Content Moderation or the `publishcontent` module or something like that), allowing them to alter published/unpublished status.

Answer (score 0):

An option is to use this module: https://www.drupal.org/project/permissions_by_term. It will allow you to restrict content access based on taxonomy terms.

Another option is to edit the view at /admin/structure/views/view/content.

If you want to go deeper, you can check the implementation of hook_node_access() + hook_node_grants() + hook_node_access_records() in the Permissions by Term module.

Comment: Thanks for this (for benefit of others reading I'd also mention the [field permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module).  My question was what "Administer Content" actually did and I think I've now figured it out - see other answer.